# Can CPython be compiled with Clang?

Tags: python, c, clang, cpython

I'm trying to build CPython using Clang, with very specific requirements:

- [Python 2.7.14](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/Python-2.7.14.tgz)
- CentOS 6.9 (but settling for Ubuntu 16.04), x64
- [LLVM 5.0.0](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html#5.0.0)

I tried setting env variable `CC` to my clang executable location (i.e. `/opt/llvm/5/bin/clang`, but the `./configure` command fails with the following:

`configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

What flags should I set to make this build work?

Comment: You're talking about compiling the CPython interpreter itself, not a program written in the Python language, right?

Comment: fixed. Also there's no C++ in **C**Python

Comment: see the `configure.log` or similar file, it should list whatever commands it tried to run!

Comment: The error message you got indicates that your installation of Clang/LLVM is not working correctly.  There may be useful information hiding somewhere in `config.log`.  Look for "C compiler cannot create executables" in that file and edit maybe 20 lines above and below that point into the question, please.

Comment: Also, the clang compiler is pretty much used to build the CPython on *Mac* at least...

Comment: (I'm not aware of any reason why CPython _couldn't_ be compiled with clang - it's not like the Linux kernel, which uses a bunch of GCC extensions to C that Clang refuses to adopt.)

Comment: @zwol the [docs](https://devguide.python.org/setup/#unix) specifically state that: *"The core CPython interpreter only needs a C compiler to be built..."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the commenters on OP's post pointed out, you can compile cpython with clang. Here are reproducible instructions, in the form of a Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
WORKDIR /opt/cpython-2.7.14
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install --yes build-essential curl \
    # Install clang
    && curl -fsSL https://releases.llvm.org/5.0.0/clang+llvm-5.0.0-linux-x86_64-ubuntu16.04.tar.xz \
    | tar xJ -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 \
    && curl -fsSL https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/Python-2.7.14.tgz \
    | tar xz --strip-components 1 \
    && CC=/usr/local/bin/clang ./configure --prefix /usr/local/cpython-2.7.14 \
    && make \
    && make install
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/cpython-2.7.14/bin/python"]
```

```
docker build --tag cpython:2.7 .
docker run --rm cpython:2.7 --version
# Python 2.7.14
```

It is difficult to say what OP's original issue was, because it seemed like a problem with the clang installation. Looking at the configure logs would provide more information.

**Disclaimer**: Python 2 has reached its end of life, and ubuntu 16.04 reaches its end of life in April 2021.

Answer (score -4):

> tried setting env variable CC to my clang executable location

On Linux, define an alias in Bash as follows:
`alias cc="clang"`

On my system I set it as `alias cc="clang-11"`

Also, be sure to have installed all clang and llvm packages on the system.

Comment: This option was the only solution that has worked on my Debian system.

Comment: Aliases aren't inherited by subprocesses. `configure` has no way of knowing this alias even exists. This cannot possibly work.